# Set Hidden field to some value when check boxes are selected GridView using jquery in a ASP.NET web forms application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

From a ASP.NET web forms application ASP.NET page using .NET framework 2.0 using Jquery version 1.8.2 using an ASP.NET GridView control.

I need to be able to **set the hiddenfield** :  hidIsDirty to a value "true" when I click on either of the 3 checkboxes Auto-Cheque, Auto-EFT or Manual. Please tell me how I can achive this with JQuery, as I wrote the following code below in jquery which does not set the value of the hidden field. I will be accessing the hidden field in code behind (aspx.cs).

Can you help refactor my jquery code and help me achieve the requirement for the 3 check boxes?

Code is given below:

```
  <script>
      $("[id*=rdoSAPPaymentAuto]").live("click", function () {
             var parentRow = $(this).parent('tr');
                        var hiddenField=parentRow.find('input[id$=hidIsDirty]');
                        alert(hiddenField.val("true"));
        });

           $("#<%=gvPaymentList.ClientID %> input[id*='rdoSAPPaymentAuto']").click(function () {
                        var parentRow = $(this).parent('tr');
                        var hiddenField=parentRow.find('input[id$=hidIsDirty]');
                        alert(hiddenField.val("true"));
        });

         $("#<%=gvPaymentList.ClientID %> input[id*='rdoSAPPaymentAutoEFT']").click(function () {
                        var parentRow = $(this).parent('tr');
                        var hiddenField=parentRow.find('input[id$=hidIsDirty]');
                        alert(hiddenField.val("true"));
        });

        $("#<%=gvPaymentList.ClientID %> input[id*='rdoSAPPaymentManual']").click(function () {
                        var parentRow = $(this).parent('tr');
                        var hiddenField=parentRow.find('input[id$=hidIsDirty]');
                       alert(hiddenField.val("true"));
        });

    </script>

    WebForm.aspx page:

    <asp:GridView ID="gvPaymentList" runat="server" CellPadding="0" EmptyDataText="No payments found."
                        CssClass="green greenBorder setpadding" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvPaymentList_RowDataBound"
                        AllowSorting="true" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="altRowColor" RowStyle-CssClass="RowColor"
                        OnSorting="gvPaymentList_Sorting" ShowFooter="false">
                        <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Approve for SAP Auto Payment or Manual Pay Req
                                    <input id="btnAutoPayment" value="Set All to Auto Payment" type="button" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>                          
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvAutoPayCheck3" runat="server" OnServerValidate="cvAutoPayCheck_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
                                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentAuto" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption" runat="server"
                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoSAPPaymentAuto_CheckedChanged" Text="Auto-Cheque" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentAutoEFT" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption" OnCheckedChanged="rdoSAPPaymentAutoEFT_CheckedChanged" runat="server"
                                        AutoPostBack="true" Text="Auto-EFT" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentManual" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption" runat="server" 
                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoSAPPaymentManual_CheckedChanged" Text="Manual" />                              
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentPending" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption" runat="server"
                                        Text="Pending" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSAPPayment" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidIsDirty" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="310px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
     </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the working solution**
Put CssClass for your radiobuttons like:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentAuto" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption" runat="server"
                                    Text="Auto-Cheque" CssClass="rdo" />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentAutoEFT" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption"  runat="server"
                                    Text="Auto-EFT" CssClass="rdo" />
                                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSAPPaymentManual" GroupName="SAPPaymentOption" runat="server" 
                                      Text="Manual" CssClass="rdo" />
```

Below small Jscript will do the trick

```
$('.rdo').click(function () {                                      
                var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
                alert($(parentRow).html());                    
                var hiddenField = $(parentRow).find('input[type="hidden"]:first');                                       
                alert($(hiddenField).val('true'));
            })
```

Note: Please change the order of hidden field (as i am getting first hidden field)...bit lazy but you can find hidden fields by Id like...

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidIsDirty" runat="server" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSAPPayment" runat="server" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used some ideas from your code. The code I have posted below worked finally. I am relieved.  thanks Sami

Answer (score 0):

I have used any idea I got from Sami above(only person who answered thanks!) above to get the closest row. For some reason .live event worked for me(but the .click event refused to work weirdly), code is below:

```
$("#<%=GRIDVIEW.ClientID %> input[id$='checkboxid']").live('click', function() {
                var parentRow = $(this).closest('tr');                                   
                var hiddenField = $(parentRow).find("input[id$='hidIsDirty']");                                      
                $(hiddenField).val('true');              

              });
```